# How to filter an array using an array with postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I have a Postgres DB and I have table `A` with a field `category` which is a string Array.
How do i find all records on Table `A` whose category array field contains the all the strings in this array? --> ['test1', 'test2'].

Searching on google give me only when `category` is a String. But in my case it is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array containment operator `@>`:

```
select * from a where category @> array['test1', 'test2']
```

This ensures that `category` contains all elements of the right operand.